# How to compact code 'pymssql query data from sql to dataframe'?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pymssql

I write some code to read data from sql server database and find the code working. The code looks ugly. I hope export can give me some hint and instruct how to write better code.

This code works fine. But I worry that if the database is huge like one million rows. It would take a lot of time to append data to Dict. however i don't know how to make it more efficient. What's more, is there better way to construct the dataframe that i need? Can I not use dict? Thanks a lot in advance. I am looking forward to hear.

```py
import pandas as pd
col=['code','desc','group_n']
Dict={}
for i in range(len(col)):
    Dict[col[i]]=[]
with pymssql.connect(server,sqluser,sqlpass,database) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = 'select VENDORCODE,VENDORDESCRIPTION,sgp.Name from STATUSCODEMAPPING as mapping 
        join STATUSCODESET as sset on mapping.STATUSCODESETID=sset.ID
        join STATUSCODEGROUP as sgp on sgp.ID=mapping.GROUPID where sset.ID = %d
        ORDER BY VENDORCODE'
        cursor.execute(sql,(238473))
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        while row:
            #print (str(row[0]) + ':  ' + row[1] + '     '+row[2])
            [Dict[col[i]].append(row[i]) for i in range(len(row))]
            row = cursor.fetchone()
df_scmap=pd.DataFrame(Dict)
df_scmap.set_index(['code'],inplace=True)
df_scmap.info()
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 595 entries, 1 to 850903
Data columns (total 2 columns):
desc       595 non-null object
group_n    595 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 13.9+ KB
```

Comment: Instead of looping through the rows, why not just use `df_scmap = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn, params=(238473,))` ...?

Comment: Yes fetchall it is convienent. but it takes a lot of time to query a huge table which contains more than 10 million rows.(at least SQL server script needs a lot of time and memory). So i think looping through  rows(one or fixed size rows )from database would be better.

Answer (score 0):

fetchall() looks much better

```
import pandas as pd
col=['code','desc','group_n']
with pymssql.connect(server,sqluser,sqlpass,database) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = 'select almhis.ID, almhis.ACTIVETIME, alm.ALARMCODE, alm.VENDORCODE,  coler.NAME
        from dbo.ALARM as alm JOIN dbo.ALARMHISTORY as almhis ON almhis.ALARMID = alm.ID 
        JOIN dbo.CONTROLLER as coler ON coler.ID = alm.CONTROLLERID'
        cursor.execute(sql)
        row = cursor.fetchall()
        df_almhis=pd.DataFrame(row,columns=cols)
```